# ScrollTo Effect (href to div)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I can't seem to find a working simple scrollTo effect. What I want to do is very basic, it's when I click on a link in my nav bar, it must take me to the selected div id with a scrollTo effect.

This is the code I have.

```
<nav>
<ul>
<li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
<li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>

<section id="home">
  CONTENT
</section>

<section id="about">
  CONTENT
</section>

<section id="contact">
  CONTENT
</section>
```

JS:

```
<!----- Navegación Slide --->   
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('a[href*=#]').each(function() {
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'')
    && location.hostname == this.hostname
    && this.hash.replace(/#/,'') ) {
      var $targetId = $(this.hash), $targetAnchor = $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
      var $target = $targetId.length ? $targetId : $targetAnchor.length ? $targetAnchor : false;
       if ($target) {
         var targetOffset = $target.offset().top;

<!----- Funcion click + scroll al #div--->   
         $(this).click(function() {
            $("nav ul li a").removeClass("active");
            $(this).addClass('active');
           $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: targetOffset}, 1000);
           return false;
         });
      }
    }
  });

});
```

This seems to work, but it doesnt take me to the top of the selected section. It takes to like the middle of the section's content.

Comment: Edited, forgot to put it in.

Comment: Must be something stupid

Comment: title changed, more accurate.

Answer (score 0):

Use this jquery here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/4qt9h95n/1/

```
$('a[href^="#"]').click(function() {
     $('html,body').animate({ scrollTop: $(this.hash).offset().top}, 1000);
     return false;
     e.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function, it's quite easy expandaple to different click events.

```
function transitionTo(elem){

    $('html, body').stop().animate({scrollTop: $(elem).offset().top

    }, 2000, function ()  {


    });
}

// and call it with:       

$('#link').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    transitionTo('#div');

   });
```